# UITextField is not visible on SKScene

Tags: swift, uitextfield, skscene, addsubview

I try to add a `UITextField` to a `SKScene`. I'm working with Swift 3 and Xcode 8. I tried the following:

```
import Foundation
import SpriteKit

class MyScene: SKScene {

    init(size: CGSize, score: Highscore, optionen: GameOptions) {
        super.init(size: size)

        let stepsTextField = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 20, y: 100, width: 300, height: 40))
        stepsTextField.placeholder = "Enter text here"
        stepsTextField.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15)
        stepsTextField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.roundedRect
        stepsTextField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionType.no
        stepsTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.default
        stepsTextField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.done
        stepsTextField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewMode.whileEditing;
        stepsTextField.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignment.center
        self.view?.addSubview(stepsTextField)
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

}
```

But all I get is a black screen. What did I miss?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add it into didMove(to view: SKView)

By adding your code to the following function, you can see your text field.

```
    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    let stepsTextField = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 20, y: 100, width: 300, height: 40))
    stepsTextField.placeholder = "Enter text here"
    stepsTextField.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15)
    stepsTextField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.roundedRect
    stepsTextField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionType.no
    stepsTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.default
    stepsTextField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.done
    stepsTextField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewMode.whileEditing;
    stepsTextField.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignment.center
    self.view?.addSubview(stepsTextField)
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks this worked. But it seems that the UITextField doesn't "belong" to the SKScene. When i change the Scene like run(SKAction.sequence([
            SKAction.wait(forDuration: 5.0),
            SKAction.run() {
                let reveal = SKTransition.flipHorizontal(withDuration: 0.5)
                let scene = OtherScene(size: size, optionen: optionen)
                self.view?.presentScene(scene, transition:reveal)
            }
            ]))
the UITextField remains visible. Replacing the scene doesn't change the view the UITextField is on?

Comment: Got it: stepsTextField.removeFromSuperview()  Textfield must be manually removed from View.

Comment: that's great @Dinean, that's also a new thing for me to learn! thanks about that. If the answer helped you, would you mind upvoting it?